# Jquery Dialog asynchronous mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asynchronous, dialog

I'm programming an application using jQuery UI dialogs. In the function onSubmit I would like the user can confirm loading a file, but due to the dialog asynchronous mode, the code doesn't give option to confirm the user's choice. When the user wants select any option the function is already ended.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Here you're the code:

```
onSubmit:function(files)
    {   
        var bucle=true;
            var perm=null;
            if(res=="0"){
                perm=true;
            }else if(res=="1"){
                if(showDialog()){
                    perm=true;
                }else{
                    perm=false;
                }

            }

            else{
                perm=false;
        }
        res=null;
        return perm;



    },
```

and the showDialog function:

```
function showDialog(){
$(function() {
    $.ui.dialog.prototype._focusTabbable = function(){};
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:200,
      width:600,
      modal: true,
      closeText:null,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            return true;
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            return false;
        }
      }
    });

  });
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Due to the asynchronous mode, you need to wait until user make their choice.
You can pass your next step as a callback to the `showDialog` method.

```
onSubmit:function(files){
  //non-relevant code omitted...

  showDialog(nextStep)

  //non-relevant code omitted...
}

function nextStep(trueOrFalse){
   if(trueOrFalse){
      // upload your file or do anything you want
   }else{
      // do another thing
   }
}

function showDialog(callback){
      //non-relevant code omitted...
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(true);
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            callback(false);
        }
      }
     //non-relevant code omitted...
  }
```